# Linux: Compiling a kernel device driver in standalone fashion

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm compiling linux for an ARM board. I need to make some customized changes into an existing driver code present in the kernel repository and reload the driver.

I was expecting to find a ".ko" file in the driver directory after doing the make, but no such file exists. Apparently uImage/device tree image compilation doesn't work that way.

Do I need to write my own Makefile for standalone device driver compilation?

It may be a silly question, but sorry I'm pretty new to kernel/device drivers.

EDIT:
I followed the process outlined here: http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:c1_building_kernel
After git checkout and installing the cross-compiler(arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 4.9.2), I issue the basic make comands

```
$ make odroidc_defconfig
$ make -j4
$ make -j4 modules
$ make uImage
```

All the steps are successful. The last few lines of log look like

```
KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms1.o
KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms2.o
LD      vmlinux
SORTEX  vmlinux
SYSMAP  System.map
OBJCOPY arch/arm/boot/ccImage
Kernel: arch/arm/boot/ccImage is ready
Image arch/arm/boot/ccImage.lzo is ready
UIMAGE  arch/arm/boot/uImage
Image Name:   Linux-3.10.72
Created:      Sat Mar 28 22:44:45 2015
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (lzo compressed)
Data Size:    5459649 Bytes = 5331.69 kB = 5.21 MB
Load Address: 00208000
Entry Point:  00208000
Image arch/arm/boot/uImage is ready
```

EDIT 2: Path to the driver code
https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/tree/odroidc-3.10.y/drivers/amlogic/efuse

Comment: I assume you wanted to say "but no such file exists". What commands did you issue to build the kernel object? And what was the output?

Comment: Agree on wondering what the build process and output was, additionally is it possible your build system is configured to dump output somewhere out of tree?  You might try using find *somepath* -name "*.ko"  Also make sure that the Makefile in the module source directory has the module of interest enabled, either permanently or via a config option which is on.  If you get really uncertain, put a #error or something in the source and see if the build breaks - if it doesn't, your source code isn't being processed.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix - Added compilation info

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Doing `find . -name "*.ko"` gives me a list of "ko" files, but none for the driver I'm interested in. And that driver DOES gets compiled(ex. Adding a syntax error aborts the compilation)

Comment: Show the Makefile of the driver in question, or better yet deep link to the source tree where it lives.  Are you sure that it is supposed to be built as a module, and not statically linked into the kernel?  Show the state of any config options it depends on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Just added the github path for the driver. I didn't know statically linked drivers. Newbie :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining your Makefile

```
#                             
# Makefile for eFuse.         
#                             

obj-$(CONFIG_EFUSE) += efuse_bch_8.o efuse_version.o efuse_hw.o efuse.o
```

We learn that the code can be built as either a loadable module, or permanently linked into the kernel itself.

Examining odroidc_defconfig from branch odroidc-3.10.y-android mentioned in your instructions we find

```
#
# EFUSE Support
#
CONFIG_EFUSE=y
```

With the "y" indicating that the code is to be linked into the driver.  Had it instead said "m" it would be built as a module.

It's possible you could change that in the kernel config, but it might also cause problems if there's nothing setup to load the module before it is needed.

Likely simply installing the newly built kernel with the code already linked inside (ie, forgetting about the module idea) will work.

Comment: A lot of other drivers are dependent on efuse, ex. ethernet(mac address from efuse memory) . So I will always have to update kernel image whenever I change the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answers to this question.

But looking at the Kconfig file in your code, show that -

```
    config EFUSE 
        bool "EFUSE Driver"
```

And since all your driver files are compiled with this config, the above config description allows the CONFIG_EFUSE to be 'n' or 'y'. So you can only build static modules (build-in) with this.

All you need to do is change the above description to:

```
    config EFUSE 
        **tristate** "EFUSE Driver"
```

and also change the other configs in Kconfig to tristate.
This will allow your driver to be compiled as module once you select the driver as 'M' in your kernel config. Then you should be able to see the ".ko" file corresponding to the driver.

Also do make sure to use EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo) when building the driver as module so that any dependencies are taken care of when loading module symbols.

Comment: Will converting this to tristate affect the order of loading the driver? A lot of other drivers depend on efuse driver(ex ethernet), which will stop functioning if ethernet gets loaded before efuse.

Comment: When converting to **tristate**, you should take care of the dependencies.

Let's say you want to compile EFUSE as 'M' then you should take care of the drivers which are dependent on this. If Ethernet is compiled as static ('Y') then during linking time the compiler can throw error of missing symbols.

During booting, Ethernet should not be probed until EFUSE is loaded (ideally speaking), though i would need to look at the code once.
So once you load EFUSE using insmod or something then Ethernet should also get probed and should work as expected if i am not wrong.